# SQL query from date column (represented as an int) returns a datetime.date object

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a sql table with a single row. It has a column `date` with the entry `20230906`.
In the program I am using, when I do:

```
query = "select max(date) from table_name"
print("res max", cursor.execute(query).fetchall()[0][0])
query = "select date from table_name order by date asc"
print("res all", cursor.execute(query).fetchall()[0][0])
```

it prints

```
('res max', 20230906)
('res all', datetime.date(2023, 9, 6))
```

I tried to reproduce this in ipython on the same database file that the program accessed and i cannot reproduce this (in ipython, the second print is also an integer `20230906`). Does anyone know how the second was converted to a `datetime.date` object?

```
def query_sql(conn, query):
  return conn.cursor().execute(query).fetchall()
```

Comment: which rdbms are you using? And what is the data type of `date` here? Is `20001202` converted into 20230906?

Comment: If the datatype of the `date` column is really `INT`, I can't think of any way that it gets converted to a `datetime.date` automatically.

Comment: @chenzhongpu sorry, the `20001202` was a typo and should have been `20230906` . I am using `sqlite3`

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how this is happening. Both queries are fed into the same query function which does no conversion what so ever, and one is giving an int and the other a datetime. I'll edit the OP with the query function.

Comment: @Barmar so I think I may have misspoke. I thought the `date` column is an `INT` based on the return type of the first query, but I just queried `"PRAGMA table_info(byday)"` and printed the column name and type and I saw `('Column:', u'date', 'Data Type:', u'DATE')`, so it appears to be stored as a DATE in the sql database. but this still doesn't explain the 1st query produced an int and the second an datetime.date?

Comment: maybe the `max` is converting everything to an int?

Comment: Are you still using Python 2.x? Python 3 doesn't have special formatting for Unicode strings (all strings are Unicode). I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the issue, but maybe if you upgraded Python and the sqlite library it will clear up.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, unfortunately at work we are using py2, but will make the switch to py3 soon. also, when I tried to reproduce the issue locally in ipython, I think ipython was using python 3.7.4, so this issue might be specific to py2. I'll try to reproduce with py2 and see

Comment: @Barmar The specific version used by the codebase is 2.7.16. I just tried to reproduce this using 2.7.16 outside the codebase and cannot reproduce, so perhaps something is going on internally in the codebase that I'm not privy to